# Did Canada or Mexico have an equivalent of Manifest Destiny at some stage in their development?

Tags: colonization, north-america, settlement

The term *[Manifest Destiny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_destiny)* is defined as an outlook of the United States.

However, the other two major nations on the North American continent also grew from port settlements and trading posts; so I wonder if at some point in their history they also felt and articulated an explicit expansion-orientated imperative.

*Did Canada or Mexico have an equivalent of Manifest Destiny at some stage in their development?*

*If so, what explicit Acts of the Canadian or Mexican legislatures were passed to that end?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the [Convention of 1818](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/convention-of-1818/) and the subsequent [1846 Oregon Treaty](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/oregon-treaty/) might be considered here, these both predate the establishment of a true *Canadian Government*. Hence I think the following Acts and acts of the post-1867 Government and people of Canada best answer the question:

- [*Purchase* of Rupert's Land in 1869 from the Hudson's Bay
  Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupert's_Land#Hudson.27s_Bay_Company.27s_surrender_of_its_charter_to_the_Crown) and the associated establishment of the [Northwest Mounted Police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North-West_Mounted_Police);
- The unofficial and then official adoption of the Canadian motto [*A
  Mari Usque ad Mare*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mari_Usque_Ad_Mare) (tr: From Sea Even Unto Sea); and
- The commitments made by Parliament to ensure the entry of [British
  Columbia in to the Dominion of Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_British_Columbia#Entry_into_Canada_.281871.E2.80.931900.29), including the founding and
  financing of [Canadian Pacific Railway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Pacific_Railway#Building_the_railway.2C_1881.E2.80.931885) .

Comment: Not to mention the motto on the Coat of Arms of the Dominion of Canada: ***a mari usque ad mare** -  From Sea Even Unto Sea*.

Answer (score 3):

Since the accepted answer does not mention Mexico, I can add an observation here. The modern nation-state's immediate predecessor was the [Viceroyalty of New Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Spain) (and later that of New Galicia). Spanish monarchs' investments in discovery and exploitation were more important for their colonization project than any legislation (but note the issuance of extensive [Laws of the Indies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_the_Indies)). New Spain attained its maximum extent around 1800 with possessions in Florida; thereafter it, and its successor Mexico, gradually lost territory to the United States through the [Adams-Onís Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adams%E2%80%93On%C3%ADs_Treaty), Texas's brief independence, and the Mexican-American War.

Mexico's territorial expansion occurred during the colonial period, so it is Spain to which we should look for analogues to Manifest Destiny. The mother country, a Catholic state with great influence over Rome, could represent itself to be doing God's work (while conveniently extracting huge profits). Ecclesiastical sanction for Spain's domination of the New World was acquired in the [Treaty of Tordesillas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas). In light of this document, the colonizers' successful invasions and [systemic racism](http://www.bellavistaranch.net/genealogy/casta.html) once in power, and their technical and biological advantages, it seems clear that Spain believed it deserved to dominate the Americas.